# How to catch the Arithmetic Exception

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to catch the exception in the following code by using a try catch block or throws exception method .i have tried out using try catch block and throws exception method at different places in the code but i am stil not able to catch the exception

```
package thowsexception;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.rmi.AccessException;

public class IOexception {
    public  int example1(int i, int j) throws ArithmeticException {
    int k ;

        if (i == 0){
            throw new ArithmeticException("cannot Divide By 0");
        }
        return  i /j ;

//        try {
//          
//        k  =  i/j ;
//        }
//        
//        catch (ArithmeticException e){
//          
//          System.out.println("Error: Don't divide a number by zero");
//        }



    }
}
```

Main Class

```
package thowsexception;

import java.io.IOException;

public class IOexception {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ArithmeticException {
        example e = new example();
        e.example1(5,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You state, `"...i have tried out using try catch block and throws exception method at different places in the code but i am stil not able to catch the exception"` -- but you don't show us this attempt. Please fix this. Also you will want to format your code better so that folks will better be able to understand your code and your question.

Comment: Could you show your Try catch attempt?

Comment: Also, You do know also that you're doing `int` division, and what that means, right?

Comment: Edit: I've formatted your code for you.

Comment: The fact that your code doesn't actually *have* a try/catch block could explain why the try/catch block isn't working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what can you do to catch the exception

Main Class

```
package thowsexception;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        IOexception e = new IOexception();
       try { e.example1(5,0);
       }

       catch (ArithmeticException e1){

       }
    }
}
```

IOexception Class

```
package thowsexception;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.rmi.AccessException;

public class IOexception {
    public  void example1(int i, int j)  {

        int k = i/j;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can fix this in tow different ways

```
public int example1(int i, int j) throws ArithmeticException {


    if (j == 0) {// you should check j instead of i
        throw new ArithmeticException("cannot Divide By 0");
    }

        return i / j;
}
```

OR

```
public int example1(int i, int j) throws ArithmeticException {

    try {
        return i / j;
    }
    catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        throw new  ArithmeticException("Error: Don't divide a number by zero");
    }
}
```

But the first one is correct than the second one, because the unchecked exceptions represent programming error, and programming error should be fixed and Most of the times these exception occurs due to the bad data provided by user during the user-program interaction, so we should prevent these type of error instead of catch it.

Read more about [better-understanding-on-checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-how-to-handle-exception-better-way-in-java](https://crunchify.com/better-understanding-on-checked-vs-unchecked-exceptions-how-to-handle-exception-better-way-in-java/)

Answer (score 2):

Your current code states this:

```
if (i == 0) {
    throw new ArithmeticException("cannot Divide By 0");
}
return  i/j ;
```

The problem with this is that you are checking if the numerator of the fraction, i, is equal to 0. If a numerator is 0, the fraction is fine, because you aren't dividing by 0. You need to check if j == 0, because you are dividing by j.

```
if (j == 0) {
    throw new ArithmeticException("cannot Divide By 0");
}
return  i/j ;
```

is the correct code.